# cudaMemcpyToArray issue when operating on opengl texture

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to write data from an array that's on the GPU to a OpenGL texture and I'm getting "invalid argument" error on cudaMemcpyToArray

```
unsigned int id;
unsigned int width = 600, height = 600;

glGenTextures(1, &id);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);


cudaGraphicsResource *cgr;
cudaCall(cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage(&cgr, id, GL_TEXTURE_2D, cudaGraphicsMapFlags::cudaGraphicsMapFlagsNone));
cudaCall(cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &cgr));
cudaArray *arr;
cudaCall(cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray(&arr, cgr, 0, 0));

unsigned int *d_display;
size_t d_displayS = width * height * 3;
size_t d_displaySB = d_displayS * sizeof(int);
cudaCall(cudaMalloc(&d_display, d_displaySB));

someKernel <<<d_displayS, 1>>> (d_display);
cudaCall(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

cudaCall(cudaMemcpyToArray(arr, 0, 0, d_display, d_displaySB, cudaMemcpyKind::cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice));

cudaCall(cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &cgr));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your GL texture is specifying a format of RGB with 8 bits per component:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
```

Therefore there should be 3 bytes per texture element.  This is the correct computation for the size in bytes:

```
size_t d_displayS = width * height * 3;
```

but then you effectively multiply that by a factor of 4:

```
size_t d_displaySB = d_displayS * sizeof(int);
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

to use in your copy operation:

```
cudaCall(cudaMemcpyToArray(arr, 0, 0, d_display, d_displaySB, cudaMemcpyKind::cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice));
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

which is not correct.  If you change the above definition to:

```
size_t d_displaySB = d_displayS;
```

then your `cudaMemcpyToArray` call returns no error, according to my testing.